# Customize Hazelcast REST URI

Tags: rest, hazelcast

I tried various options to customize Hazelcast REST URI (**/hazelcast/rest/queues/)**. However no success.

Complete URL: http://10.128.150.222:5701/hazelcast/rest/queues/testQueue

It will be great to know **if someone had success with customizing Hazelcast REST URI to something like /mycluster/rest/customers/ instead of /hazelcast/rest/queues/**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can install Apache Webserver in front of Hazelcast and define URL rewriting rules in Apache before forwarding requests to Hazelcast.